# Implementing ITemplate and accesing control properties

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I'm trying to develop a custom GridView control with properties *OpenFormModal* and *ModalWindowWidth* and *ModalWindowHeight* and a few more.

From CustomGridView class I call an instance of CustomGVITemplate:

```
Protected Overrides Function CreateColumns(ByVal dataSource As PagedDataSource, ByVal useDataSource As Boolean) As ICollection
    Dim columnList As ICollection = MyBase.CreateColumns(dataSource, useDataSource)
    Dim cmdDel As New TemplateField
    cmdDel.ItemTemplate = New CustomGVITemplate(ListItemType.Item, "delete")
    'I CAN'T ASSING VALUE TO CUSTOM PROPERTIES HERE
    list.Add(cmdDel)
End Function
```

The thing is, I should access CustomGridView properties from within *InstantiateIn* sub inside CustomGVITemplate class, the only way I know to do it is pass these parameters through

```
New CustomGVITemplate(ListItemType.Item, "delete", ALL-OTHER-PROPERTIES-HERE)
```

I don't like this solution as I'm forced to do a lot of Optional parameters so not all calls use all properties, also, I can't find the way to define properties in CustomGVITemplate and asign values to them.

Other possible solutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The thing was I was trying to access values and proerties in CreateColumns event, when data hasn't been binded yet, the solution was to create CommandButton (or Button) in CreateColumns events and access properties and DataKeys later, in RowCommand or button OnClick events.